# Multiple records on one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to create a form that has this format:

```
Shared Fields
Fields Unique to record A
[add another record button]
```

Where the [add] button can be clicked as many times as is necessary to create

```
Shared Fields
Fields Unique to record A
Fields Unique to record B
Fields Unique to record C
[add another record button]
```

Submitting the form creates record A, B and C

**Back end**

This creates 3 record, each with their shared and unique attributes as per the fields in the form.

**Update**

One thing that is shared is they each belong to an "employer". So this should be a form_for @employer?

Thinking out loud, we could hold the shared attributes as attr_accessors on the parent, and assign them to the children in the "child#create" action of the child's controller.

Comment: You've described the front-end, what about the back-end? What data should actually be filled in?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your terminology.  When you say "model" do you mean "record/instance of a model class"?

Comment: Sorry, yes! I'll update

Comment: In your example, the relation between A, B, and C to the "parent" model is a `parent has_many :a` ; `parent has_many :b`, `parent has_many :c` and each A,B, and C `belongs_to :parent`, right?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion - it should be that A, B and C are instances of the same model.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're filling in multiple models in one form without nesting, you can't just generate the form with `form_for @something`, since you've got no single object to fill in.

I would review the database structure to see if there is a way to extract shared fields anto a separate model. But if there is no way to do that cleanly, read on.

Rails helpers for rendering object forms lay out fields in a way that Rails can correctly parse as a hash. Which, in turn, can be used to construct an object. By using this:

```
form_for @thing do |f|
  t.text_field :name
end
```

You would get a form with `thing[name]` field, that would look in `params` like so:

```
{..., thing: {name: "Hello world"}, ...}
```

See [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object) for more details on this.

*And now here's the catch*: you don't have a single object to fill in. But you can neglect that and build a form that would still get parsed as a nested hash. You just have to fill in manually what Rails would otherwise guess: form URL and object name.

```
form_for :thing, url: thing_path do |f|
  f.text_field :name
end
```

If you want to create a group of fields, use `fields_for` helper inside this form. More info [in the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for-label-Nested+Attributes+Examples), in the form it could look like this:

```
form_for :thing, url: thing_url do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  f.fields_for :something do |s|
    s.text_field :value
  end
end
```

This should render a fieldset that will be parsed as a single hash. But you may need an array of nested fieldsets in your case, so see the documentation.

Ultimately you would get:

- Hash

  - Shared parameters
  - Array of objects
  - Object A
  - Object A
  - Object B
  - ...

And now the ultimate problem – you need to add fields to the form through JavaScript, but it should know in advance what markup to add. There are many ways to tackle this problem, one would be rendering an example form for each unique model and sampling it using JavaScript.

**Edit:** coincidentally, I needed to find out how to render a "bare" (not backed by an object) form that can be copied by JavaScript and would look as an array of objects in parameters when multiple forms are given.

The tricky part is, if you use `fields_for :something`, it will yield a form for a **single** object, not an array of them. Digging around, I found a seemingly undocumented feature (digging around the code from [this post](https://coderwall.com/p/uh8kiw/pass-arrays-objects-via-querystring-the-rack-rails-way)). It's used like this (I use HAML/Slim syntax for brevity):

```
= form_for :thing, url: whatever do |f|
  = f.fields_for :stuff, index: '' do |s| #<< the `index: ''` part
    = s.text_field :v
```

Semantically it appears to mean the following: make a form that contains a field `stuff`, that is filled in by one or many fieldsets with an **empty index**. Under the hood, it generates a bit awkward field names at a first glance:

```
thing[stuff][v]   # Before, without ` index: '' `
thing[stuff][][v] # After, see the empty index?
```

The fun part of this is that you can just clone the resultig fieldset without modifying it, and Rails (or even Rack?) will resolve this set of forms into a separate object each. This relies on the browser preserving the order of fields, which is true most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

In your new.html.erb

```
<div id="formDiv">
  <%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %><br>
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.email_field :email %><br>
    <%= f.label :password %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password %><br>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br>
    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
  <input id="add" type="submit" value="Add"/>
</div>
<script>
$("#add").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "newAjax",
    success: function (html) {
      $("#formDiv").append(html);
    }
  });
});
$('form').submit(function(){
  $('.multiform').each(function() {
    $(this).submit();
  });
  return true;
});
</script>
```

This uses AJAX to add a new form each time you click the button, and when you try to submit a form, it cycles through the other forms, with the class "multiform" and submits them first.

In your newAjax.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user, remote: true, html: { class: 'multiForm' }  do |f| %>
<%= f.label :name %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
  <%= f.label :email %><br>
  <%= f.email_field :email %><br>
  <%= f.label :password %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password %><br>
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %><br>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %><br>
<% end %>
```

We use AJAX in these forms so they can be submitted without redirecting.
And last in your controller

```
def newAjax
  @user = User.new
  render :layout => false
end
```

We want to make sure our layout is not rendered with the AJAX form so we don't reload your JS/CSS files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code I used in the end. Thanks for all those who helped. Followed D-side's method, but using "Employer" as the base model. I could probably refactor this to remove attr_accessors on Employer, and instead use field tags in the view. In the end, I'm only plucking the shared values out of the "params" array passed to the controller.

Bookings controller:

```
 def new
    @employer = current_employer
    @booking = @employer.bookings.build
    respond_with(@booking)
  end

  def create
    errors = []
    booking_create_params["new_booking_attributes"].each do |booking|
      new_booking = current_employer.bookings.build(booking)
      new_booking.job_type_id = booking_create_params["job_type_id"]
      new_booking.vehicle_id = booking_create_params["vehicle_id"]
      new_booking.location_id = booking_create_params["location_id"]
      new_booking.pay = booking_create_params["pay"]
      unless new_booking.save
        errors << new_booking.errors.full_messages
      end
    end

    if errors == []
      flash[:notice] = "Bookings posted!"
      redirect_to new_booking_path
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Error: #{errors.join(', ')}!"
      redirect_to new_booking_path
    end
  end
```

In the view:

```
  <div id="bookings">
      <ol class="numbers">
        <li>
          <legend>Location, Pay, & Vehicle</legend>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Type of job</label><br>
                <%= f.select(:job_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(JobType.all, :id, :name_with_delivery), {}, { id: 'job-type', class: 'form-control' }) %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Vehicle needed</label><br>
                <%= f.select(:vehicle_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Vehicle.all, :id, :name), {}, { id: 'vehicle-type', class: 'form-control' }) %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label>Location</label>
                <% if current_employer.locations.count > 1 %>
                  <%= f.select :location_id, options_from_collection_for_select(current_employer.locations.all, :id, :name_or_address_1), {}, { class: 'form-control' } %>
                <% elsif current_employer.locations.count == 1 %>
                  <p><strong>Location: </strong><%= current_employer.locations.first.name_or_address_1 %></p>
                  <%= f.hidden_field :location_id, current_employer.locations.first.id %>
                <% end %>
                <%= link_to "or add new location", new_employer_location_path(current_employer, Location.new) %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <%= f.label :pay %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :pay, class: 'form-control' %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </li>
        <legend>Shifts</legend>
        <%= render 'booking', booking: Booking.new %>
      </ol>
  </div>
```

Where the partial is:

```
<li class="close-list-item">

<!--   Recommended: post at least 1 week in advance 
  & shift length at least 4 hours.
   -->
  <% new_or_existing = booking.new_record? ? 'new' : 'existing' %>
  <% prefix = "employer[#{new_or_existing}_booking_attributes][]" %>
  <%= fields_for prefix, booking do |booking_form| -%>

  <div class="shifts">
    <div class="form-group shift">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label for="">Date</label> 
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i>
          <%= booking_form.text_field :start, class: 'form-control booking-date', placeholder: 'Date', data: { provide: "datepicker", date_clear_btn: "true", date_autoclose: "true", date_start_date: '+1d', date_format: "yyyy-mm-dd" } %>                  
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label>Time Start</label><br>
          <%= booking_form.select(:start_time, options_for_select(
            booking_times_array
          ), { include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control booking-time booking-time-start' } ) %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <label>
            Time End
          </label>
          <%= link_to "javascript:;", class: 'pull-right remove-shift' do %>
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            <% end %>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $(".remove-shift").click(function(){
                $(this).parents("li").remove();
              });
            </script>
          <%= booking_form.select(:end_time, options_for_select(
          booking_times_array
        ), { include_blank: true }, { class: 'form-control booking-time booking-time-end' } ) %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Updated my answer with my recent findings by the way. Can't stop wondering WHY. :D