# Rails 4 Multiple duplicate forms on the same page with 1 submit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I need help and want to ask for a more complete Rails 4 response. This question is very similar to [How to submit multiple, duplicate forms from same page in Rails - preferably with one button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395970/how-to-submit-multiple-duplicate-forms-from-same-page-in-rails-preferably-wit) and [Submitting multiple forms in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11299884/submitting-multiple-forms-in-rails?lq=1).

My form appears to be working, but I am not sure what the controller especially the strong params and view should look like. Below is the partial for my form.

```
<%= form_tag @metal, class: 'form-horizontal' do %>
      <%= label_tag :metal %><br>
      <%= select_tag "metal[][metal]", options_for_select(Metal.metals.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] }) %>
      <%= label_tag :weight %><br>
      <%= number_field_tag "metal[][weight]" %>
      <%= label_tag :unit %><br>
      <%= select_tag "metal[][unit]", options_for_select(Metal.units.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] }) %>
            <!-- 2nd form same as first -->
       <%= label_tag :metal %><br>
       <%= select_tag "metal[][metal]", options_for_select(Metal.metals.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] }) %>
       <%= label_tag :weight %><br>
       <%= number_field_tag "metal[][weight]" %>
       <%= label_tag :unit %><br>
       <%= select_tag "metal[][unit]", options_for_select(Metal.units.map { |k,v| [k.humanize, k] }) %>
     <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary btn-block" %>
<% end %>
```

The parameters that get submitted look like:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"b0jT....=",
 "metal"=>[{"metal"=>"10_karat_gold",
 "weight"=>"4",
 "unit"=>"grams"},
 {"metal"=>"14_karat_gold",
 "weight"=>"6",
 "unit"=>"pennyweight"}],
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

My current controller:
class MetalsController < ApplicationController

```
def index
    @metal = Metal.new
end

def create
        array_number = 0
        3.times do
            @requested_metal = RequestedMetal.create!(metal_params)
            @metal = Metal.calculate_metal(@requested_metal).first
            array_number = array_number + 1
        end
end

def show

end

private

    def metal_params
        params.require(:metal).permit([:metal, :unit, :weight, :price])
    end

end
```

And the view just refers to variables from the 2 models:

```
<h1><%= requested_metal.metal.humanize %> <%= @requested_metal.weight %></h4>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem and what is your actual question?

Comment: I created a way to dynamically add forms, and submit them individually via AJAX here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943737/multiple-records-on-one-form/29948475#29948475 Additionally some of the other answers  there may be more in line with how you are already trying to do it.

Comment: Why would you use one controller for multiple models? And what exactly is the problem you are facing right now with your code?

Comment: I do not know the syntax for the strong params (and get an undefined method `permit' error when I submit). Also, I do not know the embed the results of the search in a ERB view. Thank you and sorry for not being specific.

Comment: My initial reaction is that you're biting off a lot at once. Have you been able to get this form working for **one** metal? Get that working and then get fancy. I notice a few form-making errors that are prerequisites to getting this more-challenging form working right.